# money.js convert currency from one value to other and backwards

Tags: javascript, html

I have to input field one with $ and other with ¥, what I'm trying to achieve is: when input number in $  it will show how much it will be in ¥ and when input in ¥ it will show in $

Html:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input id="bid_jpy" class="form-control" type="text" name="user_bid" placeholder="Your bid in JPY ¥">
    <hr>
    <input id="bid_nzd" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="user_bid" placeholder="Your bid in NZD $">
</div>
```

And JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    fx.base = "JPY";
    fx.settings = {
        from : "NZD"
    };

    $.getJSON(
        'http://api.fixer.io/latest',
        function(data) {
            // Check money.js has finished loading:
            if ( typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates ) {
                fx.rates = data.rates;
                fx.base = data.base;
            } else {
                // If not, apply to fxSetup global:
                var fxSetup = {
                    rates : data.rates,
                    base : data.base
                }
            }

            $('#bid_nzd').keyup(function(){

                var jpy = fx.convert(this.value, {to: "JPY"});

                $('#bid_jpy').val(accounting.formatNumber(jpy, {
                    precision : 0,
                    thousand : ""
                }));
            });

            $('#bid_jpy').keyup(function(){

                var nzd = fx.convert(this.value, {to: "NZD"});

                $('#bid_nzd').val(accounting.formatNumber(nzd, {
                    precision : 0,
                    thousand : ""
                }));
            });
        }
    );

});
```

It works fine when I input $  and it shows the correct amount in ¥ but when I type ¥  in $ it will not convert anything.

I read documents and tried to create two different files but didn't hellped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the answer and it was very simple:

I didn't specify  what currency I wanted to convert in NZD:

```
 $('#bid_jpy').keyup(function(){

     var nzd = fx.convert(this.value, {from: "JPY", to: "NZD"});

     $('#bid_nzd').val(accounting.formatNumber(nzd, {
         precision : 0,
         thousand : ""
         }));
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is frequently a problem with beginners when they fail to validate the JS written. Whatever editor you use, try using a JS validator to validate whether JS has been written correctly.

In this case, I believe you forgot to use a bracket after completing your `getJSON` function.

```
 $.getJSON(
        'http://api.fixer.io/latest',
        function(data) {
            // Check money.js has finished loading:
            if ( typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates ) {
                fx.rates = data.rates;
                fx.base = data.base;
            } else {
                // If not, apply to fxSetup global:
                var fxSetup = {
                    rates : data.rates,
                    base : data.base
                }
            }
); //This bracket is missing in your code
```

For JS validation, use http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: i do have them  before the last line

Comment: i use PHPStorm  as IDE

Comment: Check out http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ for $.getJSON syntax. Close the brackets after the success function.